# How can I search through the unstaged changes within magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

While working on my code, I decided I needed to change the name of a function. After making all the needed changes, I wanted to commit just just those naming changes and then continue working on what I was previously working on. Using magit, I was able to easily stage just the name changes. However, since I have a lot of changes that I haven't committed yet, I'm not sure if I staged all the changes I needed to.

Is there a way to search through the unstaged changes in magit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around and finding nothing, I found out that this was actually very easy to do.

On the magit-status buffer, simple press shift-tab while on the 'unstaged changes' line to show all the unstaged changes. Then just simply use the regular emacs incremental or regex search to look through the unstaged changes. Pressing shift-tab again on the 'unstaged changes' line will hide the unstaged changes.